# Generic @mixin for sass with multiple and varied values

Tags: css, sass

how do I create a generic @mixin in sass for multiple values with comma `,` and user might not now know how many values would each include of mixin would have?

The user might want to place one shadow in some case and may be 5 shadows in some different css style, and with different values.

What is the best approach or do we have choices?.

```
text-shadow: 0 0 5pt white,
                0 0 6pt white,
                0 0 7pt white,
                0 0 8pt white,
                0 0 9pt white,
                0 0 10pt white,
                0 0 11pt white,
                0 0 12pt white,
                0 0 13pt white,
                0 0 14pt white,
                0 0 15pt white,
                0 0 16pt white,
                0 0 17pt white,
                0 0 18pt white,
                0 0 19pt white;
```

I need to have something like this:

```
@mixin textShadow($h-shadow:$baseUnit * 0, $v-shadow:$baseUnit * 0, $blur:$baseUnit * 2, $color:white)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments):

> Sass supports “variable arguments,” which are arguments at the end of a mixin declaration that take all leftover arguments and package them up as a list. These arguments look just like normal arguments, but are followed by `...`. For example:

```
@mixin box-shadow($shadows...) {
  -moz-box-shadow: $shadows;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadows;
  box-shadow: $shadows;
}

.shadows {
  @include box-shadow(0px 4px 5px #666, 2px 6px 10px #999);
}
```