# Passing list elements as arguments to a mixin

Tags: sass

The following code works except for when I try to pass the `$gradient` to `@include background-image`.

```
@mixin compositeFill($size: 100px, $gradient:(top, #000000 0%, #FFFFFF 100%)) {

    $isTop: nth($gradient, 1) == "top";
    $direction: if($isTop, vertical, horizontal);
    $widthHeight: if($isTop, height, width);
    $heightWidth: if($isTop, width, height);

    // snipped a whole bunch of irrelevant stuff
    // this is what fails:
    @include background-image(linear-gradient($gradient));
}
```

How to pass a list (e.g. `$gradient`) to a mixin that expects multiple arguments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic @mixin for sass with multiple and varied values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229924/generic-mixin-for-sass-with-multiple-and-varied-values)

Comment: No it's not duplicate of Generic @mixin for sass with multiple and varied values. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229924/generic-mixin-for-sass-with-multiple-and-varied-values

Something needs to be done to $gradient so that it will pass correctly to linear-gradient(), and I have tried lots of things, but none of them work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass a list of parameters to a mixin that accepts multiple parameters you would want to use it like this:

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient($gradient...));
```

the **three dots** indicate that you want to fill in the arguments from the list elements ... otherwise the whole list is passed as a single argument ... and the `linear-gradient()` mixin fails (as it expects at least two color stop arguments).

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9101372)