# Sass variable with comma not working on map-remove method

Tags: sass

I want remove multi key from sass map, the code like this

```
$breakpoint: (
  xs: (
    min-width: 0
  ),
  sm: (
    min-width: 481
  ),
  md: (
    min-width: 768
  )
) !default;

$breakpoint-remove: xs, sm !default; // i need remove xs and sm key

@mixin test($map: $breakpoint) {
  $map: map-remove($map, $breakpoint-remove); // not working

  justForOutput:  $map; // not working
}

@include test();
```

Its not work if the variable `$breakpoint-remove` have multi value with comma, but work for single value.

How to make its work? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`map-remove` can remove multiple keys but they must be passed as individual parameters, not as a list:

```
map-remove($map-breakpoints, xs, sm)
```

In this case (note the parenthesis's and `...`):

```
$breakpoint-remove: (xs, sm) !default;
[...]
$map: map-remove($map, $breakpoint-remove...);
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891998/316622) the `...` tells the compiler to fill the list in as if it was being called like this:

```
$map: map-remove($map, xs, sm);
```

EDIT: rewritten to include relevant info from duplicate post

Comment: So now that the question is closed as a duplicate, you change your answer to copy the accepted answer in the original question?  That's not cool.

Comment: @cimmanon I don't see this as a duplicate question, nor is my answer a duplicate of the other. My answer does use info from the other to answer this question. I edited my answer because it was incorrect and didn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you originally thought this question was a duplicate of the OP's existing question but posted an answer anyway (which you should not have done in the first place, you should be flagging it).  Your answer turned out to be wrong.  I close the question as a duplicate, so you read the answer to the original question and copied it into your answer.  How do you figure that makes this question not a duplicate?