# What do the ... mean in a SCSS mixin argument?

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm looking at a [gradients mixin](http://sassmeister.com/gist/b58f6e2cc3160007c880) created by someone else (Chris Eppstein). In the main mixin's argument list there are three dots after the last argument.

```
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops...){
```

What do they mean? I can't find it in the documentation mainly because ... is used in many code examples to show when they have skipped an irrelevant section.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic @mixin for sass with multiple and varied values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229924/generic-mixin-for-sass-with-multiple-and-varied-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `$color-stops` is a *arglist*. It provides you the possibility of pass any number of arguments to a mixin and use it as you want.

For example:

```
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops...){
    background-color: nth($color-stops,1);
    color: nth($color-stops,2);
}
```

You can call this function like that:

```
.foo {
  @include linear-gradient(to right, blue, white, red, black);
}
```