# Passing items to an array in SASS mixin

Tags: sass

Is there a way where I could pass an undefined amount of items to a mixin?

For example I have

```
@include mymixin(#{"a", "b", "c"});

@mixin mymixin($class) {
  @for $i from 1 through length($class) {
    .#{$class} {
      border-left: #{$class}-border;
      color: #{$class}-color;
    }
  }
}
```

This way I can generate classes of buttons for example with a simple mixin and pass x amount of button class names to this mixin.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic @mixin for sass with multiple and varied values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229924/generic-mixin-for-sass-with-multiple-and-varied-values)

Comment: @cimmanon That solution doesn't really allow you to select each item through an index?

Comment: Try it and find out?